# cannot create temp file for here document: No space left on device

Tags: shell, temporary-files

When POSIX shell scripts use `here documents`, a temporary file is created. Is there any way to environmentally control WHERE (path) these temporary files get created?

I am currently developing an Ant script that launches remote `POSIX operating system shell scripts on Linux, SunOS, HP-UX and AIX`.Scripts compile `C++ source code using GNU Autoconf/Automake`.  The generated `configure` script itself makes use of several `here documents`.  If any of those `here documents` cannot create a file at `/var/tmp` (on SunOS) a chain reaction of failed configure script tasks results in missing binary files due to failed attempts to compile C++ code.  :-(

So,I could keep cleaning up `/var/tmp`.  But these `POSIX servers` are heavily used by nightly, long-running jobs that temporarily eat `/var/tmp` space then give it up, sporadically causing `No space left on device` outages.  Obviously, some system administration could alleviate this problem--grow the `/var/tmp` partition perhaps.

But that is neither here, nor there, really; I want to remove the dependency upon other file `systems/partitions entirely`.  I want my entire scripted system to be self-contained, so that hiccups with `/var/tmp` space do not matter to my Ant system when a remote POSIX platform runs out of a puny amount of `/var/tmp` space. Nonsense.

In a perfect POSIX world, I should be able to control the location (path) used by all shell script 'here documents' right?  There has to be a configurable way; but all I have found is a way to control the location of 'vi' temporary space using an .exinit file with a `directory=~/tmp` command.  Isn't the same idea implemented by the original UNIX gods for the POSIX shell script here documents?

Tried the following ideas; they didn't make a difference:

```
export TEMP=~/tmp
export TMP=~/tmp
```

To reproduce the problem, fill /var/tmp (your POSIX system might be using /tmp) 100%, then try saving the following script to **tst.sh**.  Then make it executable with **chmod +x tst.sh**.  Then run **tst.sh** by typing it at the shell prompt, of course.

```
banner <<zzz23EndOfMessagezzz23
E-mail your noontime orders for pizza to the system administrator.
    (Add an extra dollar for anchovy or mushroom topping.)
zzz23EndOfMessagezzz23
```

Thanks for any leads in advance gurus!

Comment: There is only 1 question at the top; in the first 2 sentences. The rest is details to help discourage obvious answers, like 'rm /var/tmp/*' and "make the /var/tmp file system bigger, etc., which I do not consider answers to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bash:

> TMPDIR If set, bash uses its value as the name of a directory in which bash creates temporary files for the shell's use.

With Zsh:

> ```
> TMPPREFIX  A pathname prefix which the shell will use for all temporary files.  Note that this should include an initial part for
>            the file name as well as any directory names.  The default is `/tmp/zsh'.
> ```

If your POSIX shell doesn't have such feature, the best thing I know is that you modify your own shell by source code to read the value of the exported variable where if valid and writable, use it for temporary files. If not, go back to default. If you're concerned about probably security troubles with it, consider making the change permanent. If you're conservative about possible bugs or system malfunctions that may arise from the modified shell, consider renaming it as another binary e.g. `/bin/modsh` or `/bin/testsh`.

If you a large memory, you can consider mounting `tmpfs` to your `/var/tmp` but this may only apply to Linux. I'm not sure about other systems. Linux's `tmpfs` shares the memory it uses i.e. when not in use, other programs can use it. It's pretty stable and is even more stable if used with along with a swap. And `tmpfs` can have a specified size limit.

Comment: TMPDIR does it for me, but for some reason, only if I modify the actual configure script, even though I exported TMPDIR.  I'm thinking that since configure starts with "#! /bin/sh" at the top, a new shell environment is created (with its own TMPDIR) and for whatever reason, you have to explicitly set TMPDIR within configure in order for it to "take" as if the parent shell that exported TMPDIR never did so.  Wierd, anyway, I have a solution using TMPDIR, so thanks!